# Different implementation of for each to order a map contents

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a Map as shown below.

```
Map<String, List<String>> fileMap = th.getFileTranslateWordMap();
```

The key is of type String while the value is of type list.

The map may contain any number of such key-value pairs.

I am using a for each loop to display key and value pair.

The output looks something like below:-

```
Set2.txt/[binnikemask, vÃ¥gat, cognac]
Set1.txt/[tuffing, attityd, underskott]
Set3.txt/[rseelse, spjÃ¤la, ljud]
```

Here Set2.txt,Set1.txt and Set3.txt are keys, while whatever is enclosed in square brackets is value.

I need to fetch the first value (binnikemask) of first key (Set2.txt) followed by first value(tuffing) of second key Set1.txt 
followed by first value(rseelse) of third key Set3.txt

Now since I have 3 values I should sort them and store in an arraylist.

Then I need to go the second value of first key followed by second value of second key followed by third value of third key.
Sort it and store in the same arraylist.

I should keep on repeating this procedure until I am finished with all the words.

I am using Java 8.

```
Map<String, List<String>> fileMap = th.getFileTranslateWordMap();
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    arrlist.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(arrlist);
```

The above code nippet adds all the values of all the keys into arraylist.
It does not add as expected.
I have to include sorting logic to it.

Comment: SortedSet, SortedMap and their implementations are your friend (you can also define custom comparators if needed).

Comment: Are all the lists the same length? Do you know the length beforehand?

Comment: Add your expected output to your question. Your sorting requirements are unclear.

Comment: @Gunnar 
Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all lists contain exactly 3 values it can be solved easily using Java 8 Streams API:

```
Map<String, List<String>> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
fileMap.put("Set1.txt", Arrays.asList("tuffing", "attityd", "underskott"));
fileMap.put("Set2.txt", Arrays.asList("binnikemask", "vågat", "cognac"));
fileMap.put("Set3.txt", Arrays.asList("rseelse", "spjäla", "ljud"));
List<String> values = IntStream.range(0, 3)
        .<Stream<String>>mapToObj(index ->
            fileMap.values().stream().map(list -> list.get(index)))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(values);
```

This code will output the following line:

```
[binnikemask, tuffing, rseelse, vågat, attityd, spjäla, cognac, underskott, ljud]
```

If you need to sort the values within each triple independently you can add `.sorted()` at the right place e.g. `fileMap.values().stream().map(list -> list.get(index)).sorted())` and your output then will be:

```
[binnikemask, rseelse, tuffing, attityd, spjäla, vågat, cognac, ljud, underskott]
```

Comment: An arbitrary number of files is no problem as long as for each key (file) we have a list with exactly 3 values.

Comment: Hi Markus,
Thanks for responding.There can be 'n' number of keys (files).Hence it could go from Set1......SetN.txt.Should I place the above logic in a foreach loop?
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : fileMap.entrySet())
{ System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());}
The 'entry.getKey()' would give us Set1.txt...setN.txt while the values would be obtained by 'entry.getValue()';
But it would throw an error message as 'The method put String,list<String>) in the type Map <String,list<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String,list<list<String>>)'
Thanks

Comment: Sorry Markus! There are some issues with internet connectivity hence I could not complete my first comment.
Apologies !

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.Thanks @Markus ! Without your logic it would not have been possible.
I just modified Markus' solution according to my need as follows:-

```
List<String> values = IntStream.range(0, 50)
            .<Stream<String>>mapToObj(index ->
                fileMap.values().stream().map(list -> list.get(index)).sorted())
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(values);
```

Thanks all for your solutions.